# How to identify a drive's distro/OS based on its root folder

Tags: distributions

I have several hard drives loaded with Linux/UNIX-style operating systems. Is there some way to tell the distribution or operating system installed on the drive without booting into each individually? I thought I might be able to open each drive in a GUI as root and check their `/etc/issue` but that file doesn't appear to be on all of the drives.

Comment: I asked for identifying markers, not necessarily a shell script, though perhaps related

Comment: By looking at the solution(s) of the suggested duplicate you should be able to see how the identification is made, and from that derive your distribution markers.

Comment: It's one method, and I'm not unappreciative, but it isn't the only method (and thus not a *duplicate* of the question...)

Comment: Since the HDD's OS is not the running OS, I think you could take the file-based methods from the listed Q.

Answer (score 0):

There is no common file that can be used to identify the OS/Distro version across different Linux/Unix versions. Your best bet would be to check for  *-release file in /etc . Please check out the script in [this link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/27932-how-know-linux-distribution-i-am-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you know which distros *could* be on the drives, you could write a simple flowchart-style script to check package managers, default shells, and other unique configuration elements.